# slide to the right with next();

Tags: jquery, html, css

What im trying to do is the next time i click .div the last one animates and make what else function does, i still dont figure how to do that

```
$(".div").click(function() {
    /*with this code i make that the next time i open .show, the last one closes */
    $(this).next('.show').slideToggle();
    $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    /*here i use a flag to slide a div and make some animations*/
    if (!$(this).hasClass("flag")) {
        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft: '-=400px'
        }, 100);
        $(this).addClass("flag");
        $(this).find("h1").animate({
            backgroundColor: 'black'
        }, 500);
        $(this).find("h1").css("color", "white");
        $(this).find("h1").addClass("class1");
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft: '+=400px'
        }, 100);
        $(this).removeClass("flag");
        $(this).find("h1").animate({
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }, 500);
        $(this).find("h1").css("color", "black");
        $(this).find("h1").removeClass("class1");
    };
    return false;
});
```

Comment: could you post html as well ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Godeolo/9au1qhhx/1/ here,

Comment: the part that im trying to animate is this one                                       <div class="div">

            <h1 style = "cursor:pointer;"  name="hola" class="helvthinfont divs ">#PRODUCCIÓNPOÉTICA</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="show ">

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Godeolo/9au1qhhx/3/ this is the important part i guess, sorry for the mess

Comment: Your code [seems to be working](https://jsfiddle.net/9au1qhhx/4/). What specifically is the problem?

Comment: my code works but i need to figure how to make that the next time i click another .div the last .div makes what else function does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest hiding all other items while toggling the clicked item.

In my demonstration below, I created two functions: one to "toggle" and one to "hide" items.
Items are shown/hidden by manipulating an "open" class and sliding the associated content.
When an item is clicked, all items that are *not* clicked are hidden and the clicked item is toggled.

I used a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to animate the heading, but you could use jQuery if you prefer.
It's more difficult to achieve a "slideDown" effect using CSS transitions, so I used jQuery for that.

I also chained `.first().click()` to the end of my click handler's selector so that the first item will open automatically.

```js
var $containers = jQuery('.container');

function toggleItem($item) {
  $item.toggleClass('open');
  $item.find('.content').slideToggle(200);
}

function hideItem($item) {
  $item.removeClass('open');
  $item.find('.content').slideUp(200);
}

jQuery('h1',$containers).on('click', function() {
  
  var $container = jQuery(this).parent();
  
  hideItem($containers.not($container));
  toggleItem($container);
  
}).first().click();
```

```css
.container {
  font-size:14px;
}
.container .content {
  display: none;
  margin:1em 0;
}
.container h1 {
  font-size:1.5em;
  margin:0;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: padding-left .2s, color .2s, background-color .2s;
  transition: padding-left .2s, color .2s, background-color .2s;
}
.container.open h1 {
  padding-left: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
  <div class="content">CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
  <div class="content">CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
  <div class="content">CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT</div>
</div>
```